# getting the USB number of a network interface (ra0)

Tags: linux, wifi-driver

i'm using Linux (similar to ubuntu, 2.6.38) and connect multiple network adapters via USB.
i want to find the USB number of where the adapter is currently connected.
- usb-serial devices, for instance, have ttyUSB handlers so i can used `udevadm` to get its USB location (e.g. '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.3/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ttyUSB0')
 - ethernet devices (and USB-to-ETH adapters) has the 'device' node in `/sys/class/net/ethN/device` which refers to the device filesystem.

i'm searching for another tricky way to find the same thing for a WiFi USB-dongle i connect.
The WiFi is based on ralink, and i'm using the rt5370sta.ko module to make it work.
so it works, and creates the `ra0` interface, but i don't find a way to get it's USB number.

i tried searching `ra0` in `/sys/devices`, but all i get is `/sys/devices/virtual/net/ra0` which doesn't help a lot.

is there an offline solution that doesn't require checking dmesg/udev (i less prefer these kind of solutions)?

Comment: Will `lsusb` do?

Comment: i can't identify which ra is which when i have more then 1

Answer (score 0):

`lsusb | grep ralink` or `lsusb | grep rt5370` should print the info about the ralink dongle. If that doesn't

return anythin do `lsusb | less` and go through the list manually...

Comment: in this way, if (and probably will) i have 2 dongles of the same chip then i'll have ra0 and ra1. i can't use lsusb to understand which is which.